# Excel, how can I link multiple spreadsheets to cells with changing values?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, worksheet

I have a bit of a situation that I can't seem to be able to resolve. I'm currently using excel to keep track and sort 50 patients at the same time for research purposes. So in my main worksheet, A1:A50 are the patient's "station number" and B1:B50 are the patient's names. Columns "C" through "I" contain information about each patient (sex, gender, ecc.). I keep the patients sorted by their station number.
I then have a different worksheet for every patient in which I keep track of each patient's blood tests during time.

I'm trying to find a way so that I can click on a certain patient and get re-directed to his/hers bloodtest worksheet. And I've done so with hyperlinks. The problem is that patients constantly change, as do their station numbers.
For example, patient John Doe has "station number" 001, so he is on the top of my list. His station might change the week after to 005, so I manually copy/paste his info in row 5. This way, every time I cancel a patient I lose the hyperlink and need to manually search for the worksheet and re-link it to the new patient.

Is there any way in which I can lock a hyperlink to a cell regardless whether or not it is empty? This way I could move patients up and down my chart & change cell values without worrying about messing up the hyperlinks. 
I also tried to create a chart with 50 rows in which every time I changed a station number a macro would then sort all the rows. It turned out to be a dead end as I was able only to get the macro to copy/paste the patient's info into the correct row instead of it replacing the row.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't have any unique and constant value for patient, this is bad design and you should consider rebuilding your application. I think, the solution shall be database based, not spreadsheet based, for example Access.

Comment: I agree with @MarcinSzaleniec. This is exactly what database programs are intended for. Can it work in Excel? Possibly. But database can cross reference your patients much better than Excel can.

Comment: Maybe the hyperlink formula is of use: =HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!A1","Link to sheet 1 cell A1"). So if your sheet is named "John Doe" and you have "John Doe" in cell B1 you can use something like this =HYPERLINK("#'" & B1 & "'!A1", B1) to link to A1 in that sheet. But not sure if I really understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The link below probably has the simplest solution I have seen for creating dynamic hyperlinks based on changing cells.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4030-excel-dynamic-hyperlink-to-another-sheet.html

Also, see this link.

https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013034_Creating_a_Dynamic_Hyperlink.html

Finally, consider this...create a hyperlink that is dynamically linked to a cell value, in which the cell value points to a cell reference within a worksheet, and that when the value is changed can point to a different cell reference.

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A"&Z1)
```